# How can I install opencv 3.4.6 for python3.7 on raspberry pi?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I cannot manage to install openCV for python3.7 on my raspberry pi with the latest rasbian. I need openCV for an old tool I've written in the past under python3.4. Back then openCV was obtainable through pip. When I try

```
$ pip3 install opencv-python
```

I get following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python

So I am trying to compile the source files but then again when I execute

```
 cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D ENABLE_NEON=ON ..
```

I get following error:

> Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/home/pi/opencv-3.4.6/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also "/home/pi/opencv-3.4.6/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

CMakeError.log:

> Build output check failed:
>       Regex: 'command line option .* is valid for .* but not for C++'
>       Output line: 'cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wmissing-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++'
>   Compilation failed:
>       source file: '/home/pi/opencv-3.4.6/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx'
>       check option: ' -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations  -Wmissing-prototypes

Comment: Don't you just mean `pip3 install opencv-python`?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo creating this post. Thanks @DanielRoseman